# 10+ gig file reading problems Python

Tags: python, file, memory

3 Files are to be read line by line, hence:

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

or

```
for line in open(file):
    print line
```

Tried both line by line readers, but as soon as the file sizes start exceeding 10 GB python chooses to try and read the whole file into memory anyway... (works fine for file sizes <10 GB)

Any idea why?

Comment: Is the 10gb line split up properly? Maybe the 10gb file is just one long line

Comment: unless you have one incredibly large line it should not read it all into memory

Comment: what does `wc -l filename` show

Comment: how do i check, it shouldnt have done, but it sounds possible

Comment: Is it a binary file? Do you really print 10GB to the console?

Comment: How are you measuring that "python chooses to try and read the whole file into memory?"

Comment: you were right about the one big line. Many thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an optional parameter to limit how many characters you can read at a time:

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
    line = f.readline(max_chars)
    while line:
        print(line, end='')
        line = f.readline(max_chars)
```